# Breaks in a heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to use breaks in a heatmap:

```
col_breaks = c(seq(-4,-1.99999,length=100), 
                seq(-2,1.999999,length=100),
                seq(2,4,length=100));
 png("../graphs/mRNA_levels.png",
     width = 5*300,
     height = 5*300,
     res = 300,
     pointsize = 8
 );
 heatmap.2(x = t(scale(t(exp.data.breast))),
           main = "chemokine levels in tumour samples",
           trace = "none",
           margins = c(5,5),
           col = my_palette,
           breaks=col_breaks                                       
    );
```

I get this error.

> Error in image.default(1:nc, 1:nr, x, xlim = 0.5 + c(0, nc), ylim = 0.5 +  : 
>     must have one more break than colour

Could anybody explain what the problem is in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your colorRampPalette properly? Check that and for instance use three different colours like:

```
my_palette<- colorRampPalette(c("white","lightskyblue","navyblue"))
```

If that does not work, then try to remove the length in seq argument to see if it works on defult.